mds_stores (Spotlight Storage) gone wild after update to macOS 15.1 (Sequoia)
On my M3 Max MacBook Pro (released Nov 2023 and coming with macOS 14.0.1 Sonoma preinstalled), I have never had a single Spotlight issue in its almost one year of life.
Last week, I finally took the plunge and upgraded to Sequoia from 14.7 to 15.1. Besides the System Settings search bar issue described here, which was resolved, the mds_stores process keeps being at the top of the Energy page list in Activity Monitor. There appears not to be any real performance penalty, but it is annoying to have it run and run for days without end.
Something that is influencing my workflow, instead, is the fact that something (possibly mds_stores) is preventing me from ejecting an SSD. On such SSD (Crucial X8 2TB), I have 2 volumes, one with 1.25TB quota for Time Machine, and one for my GOG Library.
Every evening, I connect it to perform the TM backup, which macOS still performs flawlessly. I then hold down Option, right-click on either volume on the Desktop and press "Eject 2 volumes". In Sonoma, this never failed, just never. Since upgrading to Sequoia, instead, the TM volume ejects immediately, while the other does not.
I now leave it to think for a few minutes, then hit Try Again and, when it fails once more, I press Force Eject (as I just cannot turn off the Mac each time I need to eject a drive, I hope you can relate).
What could I do to:

solve this?
understand what is happening and why?
avoid this from happening again in the future?

I wonder if I should have not upgraded to Sequoia, besides the nice reviews around. I thought that 15.1 was safe enough.
Thank you for your help!

Maybe verify that those two external partitions are NOT included in the list of devices that TimeMachine scans?  System Settings > Time Machine > Options > Exclude from Backup ...

They are both in the "Exclude from Backup" list. They were like that in Sonoma already, and I don't think this should be changed. Right?

I don't know. Personally, I'd try removing them and adding them back in, assuming it's really mds_stores running on them. 'lsof' doesn't show other culprits? If you're logged in as administrator, does Activity Monitor show the open files for the mds_store process? (just wondering out loud).

Sadly it doesn't but, perhaps more sadly, ChatGPT had a nice idea: try to check Console for errors. Filtering for mds gave errors every 1-2 seconds, about something that either was already in index or had a wrong inode. In this case ChatGPT suggested force quitting mds_store. After doing that the process restarted on its own, but never reached disturbing levels any longer, and I could also easily eject the disks! I hope this will persist after a shutdown and restart in the weekend.
